# FIlter query set based on condition on individual object

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to return a query set based on condition that users org is in a many to many field of an object.

My ListAPIVIew:

```
class ListCoursesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        catalogue_items = CatalogueItem.objects.filter(tenant=self.request.user.tenant)
        org_catalogue_items = []
        organisation = self.request.user.organisation_unit.org
        for item in catalogue_items:
            if item.organisations.count() > 0:
                if organisation in item.organisations.all():
                    org_catalogue_items.append(item)
                return org_catalogue_items
        return catalogue_items
```

CatalogueItem Model:

```
class CatalogueItem(Enrollable):
    admin_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    organisations = models.ManyToManyField(Organisation, blank=True)
```

If organisations field is empty,i want to only filter by tenant,if organisations is non empty,i want to check logged in user's organisations is in the many to many field.

This doesnt return the correct result.I want to return catalogue_items array if many to many field is empty.If not empty it should return a queryset based on if an object is in the many to many field

Comment: Is it possible to share the relevant models and explain *what* you want to retrieve?

Comment: ok @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to filter a many-to-many relation manually. Django can filter over such relations as well. You can thus retrieve a queryset of `CatalogueItem`s for which tehere is an `Organization` in the organizations that is the same as `self.request.user.organization_unit.org` with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

CatalogueItem.objects.filter(
    Q(organizations=self.request.user.organization_unit.org) |
    Q(organizations=None)
    tenant=self.request.user.tenant,
)
```